# GPS based wind speed calculation for radiosonde device

Tags: performance, gps

I am working in a research project on calculating the wind speed using radiosonde prototype device which is device free moving under balloon to send the weather data in the upper layer to fixed base station till it reach 30 km above the sea level and drift distance about 300 km , the device has Gps receiver attached for navigation, i want to Estimate the wind speed and direction using the Gps differential calculation between the moving Gps receiver in the flying body and the GPS receiver in the fixed station. i have searched too in this topic and i found that most technique used in radiosondes is the differential Gps correction for the Gps speed using doppler shift . I want to know what is the exact algorithm should i use,  should i get the doppler shift from the moving receiver and the fixed and correlating together? or I may only get the  speed calculated from the moving receiver and the fixed and make differential correction between them .Thanks for your support .